# Change fill of svg on hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to change fill color of my svg on hover. This is what I have but it doesn't work,
tried lot of stuffs but cant make it. Any ideas why?

```html
<svg width="79px" height="79px" viewBox="0 0 101 101" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="g" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <rect id="rec" x="0" y="0" width="101" height="101"></rect>
        <g transform="translate(20.000000, 33.000000)">
            <path d="..." fill="#E0E0E3" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
    <style>
        #g{
            fill:red;
        }
        #g:hover #rec {
            fill: blue;
        }
</style>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you sent works on stackoverflow embed snippet. but i assume it doesn't work in react.

move the style into a separate css file and then import it in the top of your react component, and it'll be fixed.

Edit: So this will be the react component

```
import './changefillonhover.css';
const ChangeFillOnHover = () => {
 return (
   <svg
     width='79px'
     height='79px'
     viewBox='0 0 101 101'
     version='1.1'
     xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
     xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
   >
    <g id='g' stroke='none' strokeWidth={1} fillRule='evenodd'>
      <rect id='rec' x={0} y={0} width={101} height={101} />
      <g transform='translate(20.000000, 33.000000)'>
        <path d='...' fill='#E0E0E3' fillRule='nonzero' />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
 );
};
```

and this is the css:

```
#g{
  fill:red;
}
#g:hover #rec {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Comment: Done. In the meantime I found very simple solution - set fill on rect as "none" wrap <svg> in a component in a div and there set the background and background after hover.